# Bootstrap clearfix only on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code I have for the navbar, which works great on desktop.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="border-bottom-width: 2px;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div clss="navbar-header">
      <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" style="border-color: #4c4c4c;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mainNavBar">
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

But my problem is that in mobile, when extended it looks weird: [image]

Now I can add a clearfix div just before the navbar-collapse and that works great in mobile, but not on desktop. Here are mobile and desktop versions **with** clearfix div: [image]

Desktop **with** clearfix: [image]

Desktop **without** clearfix (i.e. how it should be)[image]

Is there a way I can use clearfix only when in mobile or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one of the responsive utility classes...

`<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>`

http://www.codeply.com/go/T5V1jGonDY

Answer (score 0):

You have coded wrong nav structure that is why this problem arises.

Kindly Remove the div tag inside this mainNavBar div.

See this example: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Make changes in your code as below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="mainNavBar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Follow the proper structure of bootstrap no problem will arise.

Hope this will help you. Let me know if there will be any problem?